# I get creases on my 3d model when I shade it smooth

Tags: modeling, error

I am new to blender and I couldn't find any solutions for this issue. Is there a way how I can fix this?
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe inner faces or overlapping vertices? If you don't find please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: enable auto smooth to fix that https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWB2J.png